# PowerBI: Ranking of songs based on number of votes

Tags: powerbi, dax

I do have a table `songs` with several fields; among them: `songs[title])`, with songs titles, obviously, and `songs[votes]`, with the number of votes every song has received.

I'd like to create a measure using `RANKX()` in order to add it to a new table (a PowerBI widget, I mean, not a table from my data model) with those both fields (`songs[title])` and `songs[votes]`) so it tells me the rank position of every song based on the number of votes it has.

I have tried:

```
songs_ranking = RANKX(ALL(songs), MAX(songs[votes]))
```

However, all songs end up ranked #1, as if `ALL()` were not able to remove row context for each song:

[image: Ranking table]

Any hint? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
_rank:=RANKX(ALL('fact'),CALCULATE(MAX('fact'[Vote])),,ASC,Dense)
```

Comment: Thanks! Why that double comma?

Comment: The syntax of `RANKX` is following `RANKX ( <Table>, <Expression> [, <Value>] [, <Order>] [, <Ties>] )`. In the solution above, I did not provide any input for `[, <Value>]`; hence, double comma.